# Bold only one portion in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am currently building a macro that will create a Powerpoint from an excel workbook. I have two cells that I currently combine into one powerpoint textbox. I want to be able to bold one cell value in the textbox. Is this possible?

This is my current code:

```
Proj = Sheets("Bay du Nord").Range("A23")
Proj2 = Sheets("Bay du Nord").Range("B23")


Set LCProj = Slide2.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=210, Top:=265, Width:=110, Height:=100)
With LCProj
    .Name = "LC Proj"
    With .TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = Proj & vbNewLine & Proj2 & vbNewLine & "kg CO2/BOE"
        .Font.Size = 12
        .Font.Bold = False
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter
    End With
    With .Fill
        .TwoColorGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 2
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(140, 0, 0)
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(180, 5, 0)
    End With
    .Shadow.Type = msoShadow14
End With
```

Say I want to bold the value that is in cell A23 (Proj) and leave the value in B23 (Proj2) the same.

Thanks

Comment: [TextRange.Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.textrange.characters) would probably let you highlight only one section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`TextRange.Characters()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.textrange.characters) to change the properties of a subset of the original `TextRange` like so:

```
Proj = Sheets("Bay du Nord").Range("A23")
Proj2 = Sheets("Bay du Nord").Range("B23")


Set LCProj = Slide2.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=210, Top:=265, Width:=110, Height:=100)
With LCProj
    .Name = "LC Proj"
    With .TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = Proj & vbNewLine & Proj2 & vbNewLine & "kg CO2/BOE"
        .Font.Size = 12
        .Font.Bold = False
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter
            With .Characters(1, len(Proj))
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With
    End With
    With .Fill
        .TwoColorGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 2
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(140, 0, 0)
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(180, 5, 0)
    End With
    .Shadow.Type = msoShadow14
End With
```